# How to substantially decrease mySQL query processing time?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a trouble that my query in mySQL is being processing about 8-10 minutes before report finally appears. I have created few indexes and time has fallen till 2-3 minutes. But that's seems too long either.

Is it some way to make some integration with ElasticSearch, Sphinx or something like this to support mySQL in making difficult requests.

1. There are about 10 tables, each is 30-40k rows with 9-10 columns.
2. Full DB size is less than 100M. Data mainly are INT, DOUBLE or VARCHAR.
3. Request is something like this:

   ````
   SELECT SUM(`column1`) AS `sum` 
   FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id` 
   WHERE `column2` = ?s 
     AND `table2`.`datetime` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE(?s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')```
   ````

Comment: Any query-optimization question should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table you have in your query. Help us help you — don't make us guess at the data types and indexes you currently have.

Comment: You should also include the `EXPLAIN` report for your query.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for a help. I will make a try. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Not sure how much it will help, if at all, but a **LEFT** JOIN doesn't really make sense in a query that has a condition in the WHERE clause for the right table that isn't _IS NULL_. At best the query optimizer will convert it to an INNER JOIN for you, at worst it will ignore that the condition could reduce your rows examined significantly. Also, with the way you have written the query, and without the information Bill asked for, we are left guessing which table actually holds `column2` and `column1`.

Comment: @Uueerdo Indeed, it is very supportive of course. Many thanks for looked through query and shared your finding. Appreciate your support.

Comment: That `LEFT JOIN` is wrong. The condition `WHERE column2 = ?s` defeats its purpose since it automatically converts it to an **inner join**. Please clarify if you want an inner or outer join. Your clarification will make a huge difference in terms of optimization options.

Comment: This in not a complex query. 2 tables, one join condition, 3 filtering predicates (between is a shortcut for 2 conditions). As already mentioned the left join is overridden by the where clause (because it will not allow `table2.datetime` to be NULL). So the only avenue for performance gains is indexing, i.e. all columns referenced in joins and the where clause would need to be indexed. An explain plan will reveal what is happening. The other factor is that often these "modified queries seen in questions" do not reveal all the actual complexity of your actual query.

Comment: *Request is something like* I suggest you reveal the full query, not something that has been "simplified"

Comment: We are _we are left guessing which table actually holds column2 and column1_.

Comment: For getting response, can you edit your existing post, show the actual table/columns list (only as required to present your query... if your table has 30 columns, but you are only referring to 2 or 3, we only need to see those respectively...  Also, show some of the sample data and what you are trying accomplish by the date filters..  Are you looking for time relative to each individual table1.column to table2.date field?  Are you really looking for activity within a given time-period provided?  Showing some sample expectation output would also help.  Edit data with SPACES, not TABS to show.

Comment: Also STR_TO_DATE does (almost) nothing useful in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have had an issue in my code, because processing time was engaged with additional cycle making request to be repeated for hundred times.

Thank you for community support, I know now how to form my questions in this area in a future.